# Changing the direction of a Combo box dropdown in SWT

Tags: java, user-controls, user-interface, swt

I'm building an Eclipse plugin in SWT, and I have the following problem: one of my fields is a combo box, and in some cases it may have fairly long items as selection options. My plugin runs on the right side of the screen, so when you go to use the combo-box, the right side of  the combo box is cut off. So, my question is: is there any way to change the dropdown's alignment relative to the combo control? It seems to be permanently left-aligned... and I'm pretty sure you can change the direction in Swing (though the only place I've seen it done is in the Substance UI demo. The Combo Box tab has boxes with North, South East, and West flyout directions... for my application, I need something like the West flyout)

Note: Setting actual text limits is a last-case-scenario option; it would be quite a bit of guesswork to set the text limit dynamically (since the widget's view can be resized).

Here's a [picture](http://i50.tinypic.com/d9v8o.png) (sorry, I can only have one link and no images :( ... I need some more rep :p)

Left side of the line: Proper width - the view is the wide enough for the combo dropdown to display all the text; you can see the scrollbars on the right side.

Right side of the line: Too small - Here, the view has been resized, and the combo dropdown scrollbar (as well as some of the text) is cut off by the right side of the screen. I always have more screen space available to the left (since this is always on the right hand side of the screen), but the combo dropdown always appears to the lower right.

Hopefully this is clear enough.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the combo? The problem might be easier to understand. It seams to me you are not using layouts correctly.

Comment: Ok, posted. I'm not sure what the layout would have to do with this problem, but I guess you never know :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I understand your problem.
Use a [CCombo](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/CCombo.html) instead of a Combo. It should automatically position the drop-down list so it fits.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I came across the same problem. CCombo does the trick but it doesnt look good and it has bug like [this one](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=175474) that wont be fixed.

combo.setOrientation(SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT); does the trick for you.